# How to convert BN result into readable string or number in ethjs?

Tags: javascript, ethereumjs, abi, ethjs

I'm receiving the result in BN format. How can I convert it into actual string or number? I'm using [ethjs](https://github.com/ethjs) library to interact with Smart Contract.

```
token.totalSupply().then((totalSupply) => {
  // result <BN ...>  4500000
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Once you have a BN object, you can use `.toString()` or `.toNumber()` on it.

Per the comments below, your function isn't actually receiving a `BN`. It's getting some sort of `Results` object that has a single key in it: 0. (Presumably if the function returned multiple values, there would be more keys.)

So first extract the `BN` from the `Result`:

```
token.totalSupply().then(result => {
  const supply = result[0];
  console.log(supply.toString());  // or .toNumber()
});
```

Comment: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: totalSupply.toNumber is not a function

Comment: It's an object.

Comment: Is this in the browser? If so, `console.log(totalSupply)` and browse through it to see what functions are available? `ethjs` says it uses [`bn.js`](https://github.com/indutny/bn.js), and those BN objects have `toNumber` and `toString` both documented.

Comment: See also https://github.com/ethjs/ethjs/blob/6c2c958c8e93f133fd6c7f969c30374ca0430d83/docs/user-guide.md#bnjs-api.

Comment: It's on NodeJS server. The `totalSupply` logs `Result { '0': <BN: 100590> }` The total supply must be 1050000.

Comment: Oh, looks like you need something like `(result) => { console.log(result[0].toNumber()); }`.

Comment: Thanks @smarx. It worked. Can you update the answer also?

Comment: Answer updated.