# Ethers.js convert hex to binary

Tags: ethers.js

I am using the following code to get transactions in ether.js

```
var init = function () {
  var wss = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider(url);
      wss.getTransaction(tx).then(function (transaction) {
         wss.on("pending", (tx) => {
           console.log(transaction.gasLimit);
           }
      });
  });
```

which returns the transaction, but the data is formatted as

```
BigNumber { _hex: '0x0245e5', _isBigNumber: true },
```

How can I get the decimal value, from the hex?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert BN result into readable string or number in ethjs?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/44288/how-to-convert-bn-result-into-readable-string-or-number-in-ethjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the link in the comment above, simple call `.toString()` on the BN, for example before your `console.log`, you can have

```
    let gasLimitBN = transaction.gasLimit;
    console.log(gasLimitBN.toString());
```