# toNumber is not a function in a then

Tags: web3js

I have check this [How to convert BN result into readable string or number in ethjs?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/44288/how-to-convert-bn-result-into-readable-string-or-number-in-ethjs)

But their solution isn't working for me

```
let totalTokensMinted = await myContract.methods
          .getNumberOfTokensMinted()
          .call()
          .then( (result) => {
            console.log(result) // give 15
            totalTokensMinted = result.toNumber(); //Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: result.toNumber is not a function
          })
        this.setState({ totalTokensMinted });
```

The method return an uint256 so I need to convert it to number.

Any clue where I am using wrong?

Comment: What's the signature of `getNumberOfTokensMinted`?

Comment: Hi Ismael, sorry for not understand what signature is. But here is the function

  function getNumberOfTokensMinted() public view returns(uint256) {
    uint256 totalNumberOfTokensMinted = totalSupply();
    return totalNumberOfTokensMinted;
  }